# Microsoft Excel creating a search formula with dynamic title headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to create a formula where I can search different policy numbers through my data. I would like my header title to dynamicaly change depending on the policy type I am looking for. Let say I have a policy number with a type A, I would like to only how the 5 columns title out of the 12 stocked in my data set. Type B would need 10, etc. I want my formula to extract and show only the header title accordingly to the type of policy I am looking for so the user dont get multiple empty fields. I will only look for one policy number at the time.  Can I do it without VBA language? Like an index match function with a twist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) --attributed to [David J. Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Wheeler_(computer_scientist))

Yes, what you describe can be done with back pages or hidden rows (or columns) and lookup table formulas.

#### First Indirection: From Policy Number to Policy Type Name

Let's assume that your policy numbers and their associated types come from a database dump or an internal web site feed, it would be more convenient to paste this data directly into a back page without having to edit it or format it directly.  See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tutorial-Import-Data-into-Excel-and-Create-a-Data-Model-4b4e5ab4-60ee-465e-8195-09ebba060bf0 for a tutorial on how to populate an Excel Data Table from a database on-demand.

```
=VLOOKUP($P$N,DT!$B:$D,3,FALSE)
```

Where

- `$P$N` is the absolute reference to the cell containing the policy number to be searched for.
- `DT` is the back page with the data tables to search through.
- `$B:$D` are the absolute columns of the data table, your columns will vary, but I recommend the use of absolute columns in the formula so that the number of rows in the data table can change over time.  Note that the first column specified must hold the policy numbers; if your data is not organized in this way, you will have to add another level of indirection (e.g. another back page) that reformats the raw data table into one that can be used to perform the lookup.
- `3` is the relative column, counting from the first column specified, that contains the associated policy number information that you would like to extract (i.e. the type column; yours may differ).
- `FALSE` specifies that the lookup must match exactly, which is not the default, and would otherwise give you unpredictable results.
- Lastly, the formula will return `#N/A` if there is no match.  You can leave this in your spreadsheet or wrap this within an `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(...` or `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...` function to change the expression of the dependent pages.

To simplify things, place this formula in a cell, to be used as a cell reference in the following indirections instead of repeating the lookup formula throughout your workbook.

#### Second Indirection: From Policy Type Name to a Row of Associated Header Data

Assuming you have a finite, known list of types and columns, you can add another back page with a row for each of the known types, structured with the type in the second column and the associated headers for each type in successive columns.  Place the following formula in the first column of the first row and copy the formula down from there to all of the succeeding rows (this will be used later):

```
=COUNTA(C1:AA1)
```

Don't get fancy with this page, i.e. no title row or other formatting.  When you have all of the types listed, sort your back page on column `B`, `Cell Values`, ordered by `A to Z`.  The sort is needed for consistent results of the next indirection formula.

Like the First Indirection, to simplify things in successive formulas, place the following formula in a cell on your driving spreadsheet, to be referenced by successive formulas.  It will give you the matching row number for your type lookup table for the row that contains the header count and the list of headers to be displayed.

```
=MATCH($T$N,TT!$B:$B,0)
```

Where

- `$T$N` is the absolute cell reference to the policy type name.
- `TT` is the name of the back page spreadsheet that holds the list of types and their associated headers.
- `$B:$B` specifies the lookup column with the policy type names.
- and `0` specifies that the function perform an exact match.
- As with the First Indirection formula, the formula will return `#N/A` if there is no match.  You can leave this in your spreadsheet as `#N/A` or wrap this within an `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(...` or `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...` function to change the expression of the dependent pages.

Place this formula is a cell to be referenced by other formulas.

#### Third Indirection: Extracting the Associated Policy Type Headers

With the two indirections above you can dig out each of the associated policy type headers and blank out header (and data) columns that are out of scope.

```
=IF(COLUMN()-COLUMN($FH:$FH)<INDIRECT(ADDRESS($TNRN,1,,,"TT"))
,INDIRECT(ADDRESS($TNRN,3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($FH:$FH),,,"TT"))
,"")
```

*Copy this formula horizontally across the columns that need to show or hide data.*

Where (for the conditional of the `IF` function)

- `COLUMN()` references the current column of the cell with the formula.
- `COLUMN($FH:$FH)` references absolutely either a cell in the column or the whole column (e.g. `$G:$G`), with the first header to be listed.  The difference between this and the above will give the zero indexed ordinal of the header to show.
- `$TNRN` is the absolute cell reference to the row number value from the Second Indirection above.  This is row number in the policy type name table that matches the type associated with the policy number.
- `1` is to specify the first column of the policy type name table, which is the count of associated headers.
- `TT` is the name of the spreadsheet/page containing the policy type name table used in the Second Indirection.
- `ADDRESS($TNRN,1,,,"TT")` constructs the spreadsheet address for the first column in the policy type name table associated with the type associated with the policy number.  This is the count of associated headers for the policy type name.
- `INDIRECT(...` takes the address above and extracts the value of the referenced cell, i.e. the count of associated headers.
- Thus the conditional of the `IF` statement will return `TRUE` if the zero indexed ordinal of the current column is less than the number of columns associated with the policy type name.

Where (for the `TRUE` portion of the `IF` function)

- `INDIRECT(...` and `ADDRESS(...` work the same as above, to extract cell value of the zero index associative header in the row with the policy type name (e.g. `3+COLUMN()-COLUMN($FH:$FH)`).

*et voilà* - dynamic variable headers from policy number input.